# Message Queues use and interesting features

Tags: message-queue, messaging

I understand the basics of a message queue system, but I have no idea about the different systems out there. There seem to be a lot of open source and non-open source solutions out there.

What are some of the ones out there and which one[s] have the most unique features? [Multicast, p2p, alternative message structures, device detection, etc]

Also, are any of these systems scalable enough for heavy use on a grid or large amounts of data?

Comment: I would love to recommend my own library, but it's not distributed (though a small patch could make it so), but that would be a little self serving (and it only works on osx and with the clang compiler). But you may want to look at languages like erlang.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I specialize in one specific brand of MOM so I can't provide a complete answer.  However, after 3 days there are no other answers so I though I'd at least take a stab at this.

> What are some of the ones out there and which one[s] have the most unique features? [Multicast, p2p, alternative message structures, device detection, etc]

I'm not sure what you mean by "device detection" but WebSphere MQ has the rest of the things mentioned.  There's also a REST API, file-to-message, message-to-file, rich user-defined message metadata capability, 1-phase commit, 2-phase commit, tunneling over HTTPS, encryption on the wire, encryption at rest, API's in a dozen languages, support for dozens of platforms, automatic failover and reconnect, broker-based message filtering, etc., etc.

And that's just the one product I'm familiar with.  The messaging space is quite rich with competing products and some are purpose-built with narrow focus and others are general-purpose solutions.  Some are lightweight in-memory affairs and some are quite robust.  Sorry I can't provide a detailed comparative analysis, though.  I was rather hoping someone would, or link to a good and recent overview article.

> Also, are any of these systems scalable enough for heavy use on a grid or large amounts of data?

Oh yeah.  The offerings range from ultra safe (messages hardened to disk & replicated while app blocks) to ultra fast (messages sprayed over multicast at a rate of thousands or tens of thousands per second).  I have customers that move thousands of messages per second over a few nodes and others that in aggregate move hundreds of thousands of messages per second over a large network.

Comment: I meant device dependent, as in mobile/embedded systems could recieve a light version of the messages [compressed headers, binary format, etc]

Comment: Ah, that makes sense.  I know WMQ will soon support MQTT directly but I don't know whether it will be possible (at least in the first version) to send a full WMQ or JMS message that is automatically converted to MQTT.  On the other hand moving MQTT to WMQ will drastically reduce the cost over where it is positioned now in WebSphere Message Broker.  More at http://mqtt.org/ and http://mosquitto.atchoo.org/ for those interested. That's yet another aspect of this question I hope others will weigh in on since I have no familiarity with other brand transports.